# How to extract Heading tags value and particular text inside a div using a class in PHP from string

Tags: php, regex

i have to parse an html file using  regular expression header inside a div tag 
this is my html tag where i am trying to parse

```
<div class="descriptionArea-2" style="visibility: visible;">
<img src="(image Url Here)" />
<br />
<h2>"Product Title"</h2>
        <div class="displayDescription">"product description here."<div class="icons">icons</div></div>

</div>
```

i tried a lots of time in this one for getting "product title" and "product description here"

Comment: which language do you use to validate this url, do you do this in javascript or in php?

Comment: Which parts of the sample html may vary, and which are static? For instance, does the `div` always have these attributes? With these values?

Comment: same html structure but content may vary depend upon the products...

Answer (score 1):

i dont know how generic the pages are but these expressions could work:

Product title:

```
/<h2>"(.*)"<\/h2>/
```

description:

```
/<div class="displayDescription">"(.*)"<div class="icons">/
```

maybe a more generic way to get description:

```
/<div class="displayDescription">([^<]*)/
```

use preg_match(_all) to get the values you want

```
preg_match_all('/<h2>"(.*)"<\/h2>/',$string,$matches)
$matches[1][0] //gets the first title
```

Comment: You will have to escape the forward slash here `<\/h2>`

Comment: if there are more than <h2> how will i iterate using div class because there are more than header tag in particular html page where we are parsing this one and thanks for quick reply

Comment: you can use `preg_match_all` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: i wasnt sure if you wanted the description with or withouth the icon. and if a description always contains an icon

Answer (score 0):

Reg expression for this

```
'/<h2>"([^"]*?)"<\/h2>/'
```

use function preg_match_all

are you sure the title is in always in double quotes?

Your html code is not valid there is no closing tag for div with description

Comment: You don't have to escape `<>`

Comment: if there are more than <h2> how will i iterate using div class because there are more than header tag in particular html page where we are parsing this one

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way of getting what you want with regexps:

```
/<div class="descriptionArea-2"[^>]*>(?: *<[^h][^2][^>]*>\/>)*<h2>([^<]*)<\/h2>[^<]*<div class="displayDescription">([^<]*)</
```

The above tries to match the exact same hierarchy as the sample html provided in the question. Replace the classes strings as needed. If the `h2` and nested `div` tag (the one with `displayDescription` class) are in reverse order, or if there is any other tag in between, the regexp will not work.

The first returned value will be the `h2` text, and the second the inner `div` text.

---

Another option is to use [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath), if your html document is well formed.
Here are the xpath solutions for each string:

```
//div[@class="descriptionArea-2"]/h2/text()

//div[@class="descriptionArea-2"]/div[@class="displayDescription"]/text()
```